# String Manipulation in C to find the average of the numbers in a string

Tags: c, string, text-files

I have a text file in C in CSV format. So each row of text is a record like this:

```
bob numbers,10,11,12,13
john no,7,13,10
```

What functions could I use in C to get an output that would give me each rows average rounded up to 2 d.p. and look like this?

```
bob numbers 11.5
john no 6.67
```

Comment: Well first you need a [function to read a line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), then a [function to separate the entries](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) would be useful, then maybe a [function to convert strings to numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol). Now it's up to you to try and make a program using, for example, these functions. If you have any problem with this program, then come back here and write a detailed question about that single problem, providing your code.

Comment: If you are just learning, then `getline` or `fgets` will read a file line-by-line (`getline` provides a bit more information about the line on return). After you have read the line into a `buffer` (a string variable (`getline` will also allocate space for you), you can then parse the line with `strtok` and `atoi` -- or just using `strtod` (resetting pointer=endptr) after each conversion to a number. (**Note** this question has been answered many times and the answer is already on this site)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strtok` with `,` as a delimiter to read the name and numbers, and then `atoi` to convert the number strings to actual numbers. Also, `fgets` lets you read files line-by-line. Calculating the average is pretty elementary. Consider using `atof` instead of `atoi` to read the numbers as doubles, not integers.

Answer (score 0):

You problem can be solved as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int a[20];
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt","r");
    char buff[255],*p;
    int i,j,k;
    float sum;

    while(fgets(buff,255,fp) != NULL)
    {
        i = 0;
        k = 0;
        sum = 0;
        p = strtok(buff," ");
        while(p!=NULL)
        {
            if(i>1)
            a[k++] = atoi(p);
            p = strtok(NULL,",");
            i++;
        }
        for(j=0;j<k;j++)
        sum += a[j];

        printf("%5.2f\n",(float) (sum/k));
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your code is giving me the correct averages. However, I do have some question. first the `while(fgets(buff,255,fp) != NULL)` line how does it go through the entire text, doestn't fgets() only get one line from the text file. How does it go to the second line. Secondly the      `p=strtok(buff," ");` why cant we change that to `p=strtok(buff,",");`. I tried doing that but then I get the wrong averages. Once again Thanks a lot for all the help, I would really appreciate it if you could answer my questions.

Comment: @SSRed You have answer in your question for the first part. The `while` loop keeps looping until fgets() has not got anything to read.So that happens only when it has read all the lines. The second part about `strtok` This API maintains an internal state and we need to pass the actual string only once and the to fetch other tokes we need to pass just `NULL` as shown . If this answers just mark as answered which will be helpful for others.